# Accelerate rownorm(A*R')

Tags: performance, julia, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

In the algorithm I am writing I didn't expect the following part to be the bottleneck.
Here is a trimmed down version of my code:

```
using LinearAlgebra

A = rand(1000,100)
R = triu(rand(100,100))
for i = 1:300
    R = triu(rand(100,100))
    @views nrms = norm.(eachrow(A[i:end, :] * R'))
end
```

Is there a way to accelerate the computation of `nrms`?

I could perfectly store A transposed instead of how I am storing it now if that helps, but the impact seems minimal, for example

```
@views nrms = norm.(eachcol(conj(R)*AT[:,i:end])
```

with `AT = copy(transpose(A))`.
I also tried writing manually a loop that would avoid storing the product `A[i:end, :] * R'` but this was always much slower as no blas was used then for gemm.

Comment: The loop and the setup is a bit distracting. To make this clear: is it specifically the line with the calculation of `nrms` which is of interest? Or do you also need a faster way to generate upper triangular matrices, reuse memory, etc.?

Comment: I only want to accelerate that line computing `nrms`. In practice the matrices are not randomly generated, but come from other code. The only line of code truly in my code is the one to compute `nrms`. I don't see how reusing memory could be more efficient either as both A and R are needed for other computations in the loop and should not be overwritten.

Comment: This would indeed be true if R didn't change every loop, but here it does.

Comment: Oh that's right, sorry. Have deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beating BLAS on performance on (relatively) big matrix operations is quite challenging. But it is possible with LoopVectorization. Here's a manual loop with the `@tturbo` annotation, which is the multi-threaded version of `@turbo`.

This does not take advantage of the triangular shape of R, because LoopVectorization only works on rectangular index regions, though that will probably change in the future. Then a further speedup of ~2x should be possible

```
using LoopVectorization

function rownorm2(A::AbstractArray{S}, R::AbstractArray{T}) where {S, T}
    P = float(promote_type(S, T))
    vals = zeros(P, size(A, 1))
    @tturbo for k in axes(A, 1)
        valk = zero(P)
        for i in axes(R, 2)
            vali = zero(P)
            # for j in i:lastindex(R, 1)  # <- does not work with LoopVectorization
            for j in axes(R, 1)
                vali += A[k, j] * R[j, i]
            end
            valk += vali^2
        end
        vals[k] = sqrt(valk)
    end
    return vals
end
```

I use a slightly modified version of your code with `R` lower triangular, instead of upper:

```
rownorm(A, R) = norm.(eachrow(A * R))
```

Benchmark:

```
A = rand(1000,100);
R = tril(rand(100,100));

julia> rownorm(A, R) ≈ rownorm2(A, R)
true

julia> @btime rownorm($A, $R);
  393.700 μs (5 allocations: 828.34 KiB)

julia> @btime rownorm2($A, $R);
  77.100 μs (1 allocation: 7.94 KiB)
```

This is on a laptop with 6 cores and 12 threads. You must start Julia with threads enabled. The achieved performance depends on what sort of simd vectorization your computer supports.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, @DNF. I didn't think multithreading would have this much effect and will definitely use it. I was looking more for a reordering of operations or something similar that would avoid allocations and work column oriented. I do get even slightly better results with 8 cores and 12 threats as could be expected. The problem though is that `rownorm(A, R) ≈ rownorm2(A, R)` is not true. I do not get the same results after multithreading (in Julia 1.8.2). I used your exact code though. Thank you very much already.

Comment: That is very strange. How big is the discrepancy? And do they agree when you disable multi-threading (`@tturbo` -> `@turbo`)?

Comment: The discrepancy is large (e.g. first number goes from 153 to 107). And they do agree when I use @turbo instead indeed, but then I don't get any speedup of course.

Comment: That is very odd. I get equality every time. Perhaps you can pose this question at discourse.julialang.org?

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite difficult as optimization usually relies on unused extra information from beyond the algorithm in focus. As the question is phrased now, with random matrix inputs, it is almost asking the generic question of improving the already optimized matrix multiplication operation (like Strassen's algorithm does, but not so much, really). DNF impressively recovers all the speed of the BLAS implementation in pure Julia using the extra bit of context that only the norm is needed as output, and not the whole matrix!

The idea behind this answer is to use the specific loop structure of the calculation in the question, i.e. a constant big matrix (1000x100) multiplied by 300 smaller (100x100 triangular matrices). In order to squeeze more performance, consider generating the triangular matrices in a transposed fashion: the first column of all 300, the second... and so on. In code:

```
function way1()  # original method from OP
    A = rand(1000,100)
    nrms = zeros(1000,300)
    for i = 1:300
        R = triu(rand(100,100))
        @views nrms[:,i] = norm.(eachrow(A * R'))
    end
    nrms
end

function way2()  # new transposed method
    A = rand(1000,100)
    nrms = zeros(1000,300)
    for i = 1:100
        R = rand(i,300)
        @views nrms .+= (A[:,1:i] * R).^2
    end
    nrms .= sqrt.(nrms)
end
```

The transposed method fits nicely into the memory layout and gives the following benchmark:

```
julia> @btime way1();
  247.788 ms (2704 allocations: 291.53 MiB)

julia> @btime way2();
  138.539 ms (398 allocations: 243.50 MiB)
```

Therefore, if the original usage allows this kind of generation, there is a 40% time saving.

Comment: I am not able to reorder it, for my problem. This is an iterative algorithm and the R matrices come from a QR decomposition each iteration of the current matrix and the norms need to be used directly to select the pivot for the next iteration. But thank you for the conclusion, there is just no way to beat BLAS, so I'll settle for the current performance. Thank you!